# Apache Doesn't Detect CGI Script

Tags: apache, bash, cgi

I am running ubuntu with apache2. I have already edited my httpd.conf file to say...

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/
```

I have also created a bash script and made it executable, and placed it within within the `/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/` directory. However, when I send...

```
http://[domain]/cgi-bin/vlc-http.cgi?226625
```

I get a standard apache 404 URL not found error. I have no idea how to troubleshoot the situation, since I am new to apache and cgi.

Extra-Information: If I send an http request to /cgi-bin/ then apache tells me I don't have permission to access.

Comment: does it work if you have it (or a symlink) at $WEBROOTDIR/cgi-bin/vlc-http.cgi ? ... with proper permissions of course

Comment: Check the output of `ls -Rl /usr/local/apache2`. The user *www-data* needs `rx` permissions on all folders and files. Also check the Apache error.log.

Comment: I did the following, still doesn't work. Also, if I don't include the line ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/; I get the same behavior.

Comment: I think I have it fixed, but if somebody can tell me why apache was defaulting to /usr/lib/cgi-bin, that would help.

Comment: Did you include this in the right virtual host specification?